# Monoids and groups of fractions

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, semigroups-and-monoids

Let $G$ be a group containing a monoid $M$ that spans $G$ as a group. Is it possible to have a proper quotient $\varphi \colon G \to Q$ of $G$ such that the restriction of $\varphi$ to $M$ is injective?

More specifically I'm interested in the following: if $M$ is an Ore monoid (cancellative and admitting least common right multiples) then it embeds into its group of right fractions $Q$. There is also a universal group $G$ through which any map from $M$ to a group factors (it has presentation $\langle M \mid m \cdot n = (mn) \text{ for }m,n \in M\rangle$). So $Q$ is a quotient of $G$. Can it be a proper quotient?

In other words: $Q$ is by definition universal among the groups $\iota \colon M \to H$ subject to the condition that $H = \iota(M) \cdot \iota(M)^{-1}$. Is it nontheless universal among all groups?

Comment: From the work of Patrick Dehornoy "Complete positive grop presentations" it follows nicely, using rewriting systems (brilliant tool indeed!), that the group of quotients for Ore's monoids is universal. You may also enjoy Example 23 from a recent preprint by George Bergman http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.0564, as well as the whole paper

Comment: Excuse me to mention also this: Baumslag-Solitar monoids $\langle a,b:ab=ba^k\rangle$ have Ore's condition, but how much different is the behaviour of the BS-monoid an dthe corresponding BS-group! In general it seems very little in common between a group-embeddable semigroup and its universal group.

Comment: Does anybody know any instances in the past when Ore's monoids would appear naturally in order to do something good. I know only of Grigorchuk's proof that f.g. cancellative semigroups with polynomial growth are exactly virtually nilpotent f.g. cancellative semigroups?

Comment: Sorry, i recalled now: you may check with Simon Craik that (f.g.) Ore's monoids sometimes may be nice -- say they admit only 1,2 or continuum many ends, but i think it is still unknown whether Stallings theorem for them could be worked out (by ends i mean the more natural undirected ends rather than care about artficial in semigroups setting directions in Cayley graphs)

Comment: Sorry again, i ate biscuits so cannot stop: it seems would be really nice to understand what are the group-embeddable semigroups whose universal groups are one-relator. At least what are those with Ore's condition. You see, i'm trying to crystalise "importance" of group-embeddable semigroups, which so far only show that things are wild.

Comment: @Victor,  Ore monoids are important in Garside theory. The homology of an Ore monoid and its universal group are the same for coefficients in a ZG module.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: yes, for Graside monoids everything is good. But because homologies over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ for Ore's monoids and their universal groups -- even for $(\mathbb{N},+)$ -- are different in general, it makes no hope that ends for f.g. Ore's mononids could be calculated by analogue of Specker's formula for groups. We write about it at the end in http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.3500 with Vesna Kilibarda

Comment: @Victor, For Z/2 with constant coefficients it seems to me you should get the same answer because the classifying spaces are homotopy equivalent. Are you using constant coefficients or monoid ring over Z_2?

Comment: In general, it seems that geometry of Cayley graphs of semigroups is quite "bad notion", though of course many things are known to be nice in some good cases. May be dynamics of endomorphisms on Cayley graphs would yield something -- we studied recently with Alan Cain growths of endomorphisms of f.g. semigroups -- all is very nice, except that it is not clear why really this is important. And also, talking about group-embeddable semigroups, again no relation between growth of endo on the semigroups and growth of lift of the endo to the universal group -- because of Baumslag-Solitar, of course

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: we used monoid ring over Z_2. But what you suggest is great! Let me check it

Comment: @Victor, for an Ore monoid $M$ with universal group $G$ one has that the cohomology of M with coefficients in a $G$-module $A$
 is the same as the cohomology of $G$ with coefficients in $A$. This is because the natural map $BM\to BG$ of classifying spaces is a homotopy equivalence and cohomology with $G$-module coefficients is cohomology of the classifying space with coefficients in a local system.

Comment: @Victor, computationally it is often easier to compute the cohomology for the group using the monoid because the monoid is smaller.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg, thanks! That's fantastic, I guess we were there and missed absolutely everything with Vesna :-) Let me digest what you said and hopefully some positive thing can be found how to calculate the number of ends for f.g. Ore's semigroups -- since we kind of cast too much "lament" in that paper that nothing works.

Comment: Most likely your problem is that modules in which M act noninvertibly are not seen by the classifying space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For an Ore monoid the universal group is the group of right fractions.  This is proved just as the universal property for localization of commutative rings is proved. It is irrelevant whether $H=\iota(M)\iota(M)^{-1}$, you can simply send a fraction $(m,n)$ to $\iota(m)\iota(n)^{-1}$ and check that this gives a well defined homomorphism.  Or you can look in a category theory book for the words "calculus of right fractions" where they will prove a more general universal property for localizing categories.  Think of a monoid as a one object category and their condition that the monoid admit a calculus of right fractions is the Ore condition.

In general, the answer is there can be proper quotients.  The free group on two generators is generated as a group by the free monoid on two generators.  There are lots of groups generated by two elements which generate a free submonoid, like the free metabelian group or the lamplighter group.

Edit: Alternatively you can show that if $M$ satisfies an Ore condition and $\iota\colon M\to H$ is a homomorphism to a group $H$ then $\iota(M)\iota(M)^{-1}$ is a subgroup of $H$ and so the two universal properties are the same. It is basically the same argument as to why you can form the product of 2 fractions.

Comment: Ben, what is known about "universal inverse semigroups" for semigroups/(nice type of semigroups)? Is there any analogue to Ore's condition for that setting?

Comment: @Victor, that is a good question. I am not sure what has been done. If memory serves David Rees gave a nice proof that Ore monoids embed in their group of units via inverse semigroups (it is in Lawson's book). He starts with an Ore monoid M and shows it is the R-class of 1 in the inverse hull S and proves M^{-1}M =S. He also proves S is E-unitary and that gives the embedding. I don't remember how much still works without Ore and with weaker cancellation assumptions on M. You might look there first.

Comment: Thank you, Ben! I didn't know about this proof by David Rees.